# http based domain control validation(dcv) -commodo

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

Generated csr in aws ec2 box.   csr has a new line at the end of each line.  Copied the csr to the commodo site.  For http based domain control validation(dcv)   when i do md5 and sha256 hash do i need to remove the new line character in csr before hashing?

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/791/0/alternative-methods-of-domain-control-validation-dcv

Comment: You are not supposed to do any hashing yourself (because this is an implementation detail, the authorization data is opaque and could be any random string instead), the CA will give you the specific strings and records to put in the DNS or in the HTTP webserver. So just use those, do not try to redo things locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Comodo web site, you don't strictly need to know how to generate the hashes.

> When ordering a certificate through Comodo’s web-interface The hash values are calculated and presented via the web-interface during the order process. They are on the same page as the DCV email-address options.

If you are using the API, or you just want to know how to do it, then you must first properly encode the CSR as binary DER encoded... not PEM encoded.  This means newlines are not an issue in the hashing process -- DER files are not text.

> The hashes MUST be generated from the DER-encoded (i.e. binary) version of the CSR – not the base64 PEM encoded version.

Converting a PEM CSR to a DER CSR:

```
openssl req -outform DER -in csr.pem -out csr.der
```

Quoted are from the link you provided, https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/791/0/alternative-methods-of-domain-control-validation-dcv.